# transfering data from txt file to an array (list index out of range)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am have issues witch transfering data from my text file into my array.
As when i try to put data from the text file into the array it comes up with a list index out of range error. I just need a simple way of transfering a username and password into 2 different arrays.

```
username = []
password = []

lr = open("login.txt","r")
loginr = "temp"
  while loginr!="":
    loginr = lr.readline()
    field = loginr.split(",")
    username.append(field[0])
    password.append(field[1])
print(username+password)
lr.close()
```

The text file is layed out as

```
simple,123,
legit,scary,
smite,Oxygen31,
```

Comment: It's because you've initialized username and password as empty arrays. This means there's nothing to add to them. Either that or your line isn't being read correctly and there's no commas to split from so there's no array created

Comment: Can you show a sample of the text file?

Comment: If the problem is the fact that the arrays are empty what should put in the arrays?

Comment: The problem isn't the fact that the lists are empty because you are using `list.append()`. The exception is happening when you access `field[1]` which means that there is a bad line in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that `login.txt` file has all the lines with `username,password,`. Other than that, I would recommend using `with open()` instead of `open()` and `close()` and then you can loop through the lines of the file object or use list comprehension to extract usernames and passwords. For example:

```
# loop approach
with open('login.txt', 'r') as f:
    username = []
    password = []    
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(',')
        username.append(line[0])
        password.append(line[1])

# list comprehension approach
with open('login.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.split(',') for line in f]
    username = [x[0] for x in data]
    password = [x[1] for x in data]
```

Comment: Yeah, i went the loop approach way as the other way is a bit too complicated for me and it was working. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Glad to help :-)